# GORM column mapping not respecting underscore before number

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-3.1

I have a column in my table called `HDR_PROSHIP_REFERENCE_1` and a `mapping` in the domain of:

```
static mapping = {
    table 'ORDER_LINE'
    version false
    id column: 'LINE_ID', insertable: 'false', updateable: 'false'
    proshipReference1 column: 'HDR_PROSHIP_REFERENCE_1'
    proshipReference2 column: 'HDR_PROSHIP_REFERENCE_2'
}
```

When GORM goes to build out a query against this, however, SQL throws an `invalid identifier`:

```
ORA-00904: "THIS_"."HDR_PROSHIP_REFERENCE2": invalid identifier
```

It looks like GORM, in its effort to camelcase columns by default, is not respecting the '_' before the numbers.

Is this a bug with GORM or am I not writing the mappings correctly?

Comment: Why does the error show a `"THIS_"` qualifier in front of `"HDR_PROSHIP_REFERENCE2"`?

Comment: good question, I'm not sure. I've seen it on every GORM-generated query ever though, so I'm not sure. Works fine for every other query.